# Maximize iPhone battery lifespan by keeping it plugged into power whenever possible

Tags: iphone, battery

I know, sometimes it can explode, but is it a good advice to let the iPhone - whenever possible - plugged in to a power outlet in order to maximize battery lifespan (so it's almost always at 100%)?

If it matters, it is an iPhone Xs.

Also, I know, from time to time (few times in a month at least) every battery should be used until it's empty and then fully recharged, that's clear to me.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with your phone - the few times a month used until empty was needed before Apple made changes to the charge behavior. You don't ever want to use to empty now unless you actually can't start charging sooner and need the device. See my answer for more clarity on what used to be true and what's true for you now.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes - keep your iPhone XS and newer plugged in unless you put it in long term storage. Then 50% charge and power it off.

There is no reason to not fully charge and keep attached the latest iPhone and iPad devices that run iOS 11.3 since there are now charge management enhancements to avoid voltage pressure and lack of discharge that can cause issue on older devices and operating systems.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208710

> iOS includes a charge management feature to maintain battery health when iPad or iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, or iPhone XR is connected to power for prolonged periods of time, such as when used in a kiosk or a point of sales system, or stored in a charge cart.

Your XS is better off to leave plugged in since that reduces charge cycles. Unless you aren't going to use if for a couple months, then discharge or charge to 50% and shut it off:

- https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

---

Older devices and older operating systems do require you to balance the need to have it charged with the need to delay eventual failure. Every single lithium battery will eventually swell and/or disconnect itself electrically if it doesn't fail some other manner prematurely.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208387 - information on chemical aging of batteries
- [iPad being using in wall mount battery swollen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355939/ipad-being-using-in-wall-mount-battery-swollen)

Answer (score 3):

> I know, sometimes it can explode

To ensure this to a very high degree (no pun intended) that this doesn't happen, always make sure to use official or certified cables and accessories to charge your iOS device.

While it is true that Lithium-ion batteries age with the number of charge cycles depleted (which as I understand you are trying to cut down on), there are other factors as well that affect battery health, such as extreme temperatures and storage considerations. From the Apple Support document, [iPhone Battery and Performance](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208387):

> A normal battery is designed to retain up to 80% of its original capacity at 500 complete charge cycles when operating under normal conditions.

Additionally, there are other relevant documents from Apple that includes tips on how you can maximize the lifespan of your iPhone's battery.

- [Charge and monitor the iPhone battery](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/charge-and-monitor-the-battery-iph63eecc618/ios)
- [Maximizing Battery Life and Lifespan](https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/)

In general, you can leave your iPhone plugged into power and use it, unless the device doesn't heat up, exceeding the recommended temperature range. This could happen due to use of an unofficial/uncertified accessory, presence of a case or using an app which taxes the hardware thereby causing device heat-up.

Avoid charging or leaving the iPhone in hot environments, including direct sun exposure, for extended periods of time.

Apple also recommends to keep your iPhone updated to the latest available public version of iOS for your iPhone as Apple software updates often include advanced energy-saving technologies.

Comment: I know that documents, but there is nothing there regarding leaving it plugged in to power.

Comment: @Kr15 You can leave it plugged into power and use it, unless the device doesn't heat up, exceeding the recommended temperature range. This could happen due to use of an unofficial/uncertified accessory, presence of a case or using an app which taxes the hardware thereby causing device heat-up. I'll edit this into the answer.

Comment: Now with iOS 13 the "Optimized Battery Charging" is there (default on) to keep the battery charged to 80%, learn users charging/usage behaviour and charge past 80% right before the iPhone is used.

Comment: Yes, after all.. now with "Optimized Battery Charging" it says it all: It WAS NOT adviceable to let a iPhone XS plugged in?! Regardles of the device temperature. etc.. Otherwise iOS would not get such a feature ("Optimized Battery Charging") and prevent charging beyond 80%!

Answer (score -1):

It's actually bad for a battery to retain 100% of its capacity at all times. It will shorten its lifespan.

I have charged my iPhone 200 times now and still have 100% of my capacity. I charge it from 40 to 80 procent. Which means I've fully charged it like 75 times, but it's still at 100%. I do a full cycle once a month.

A nice read:
https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/charge-phone-properly-3619623/

Comment: this is true in general, but not applicable for iPhone Xs - Apple manages and avoids the 100% charge situation even if you leave a device plugged in. See my answer for details. Older iPads, older iPhones - yes - this is correct.

Comment: Still doesn't change the fact that an iPhone charged at 90% will have a shorter lifespan than one charged at 60%.

Every battery shipped will be charged between 50-60%. Because even Apple knows storing a battery is better when the battery is charged to half full.

Comment: You can't keep the iPhons XS at 100% charge - it will stop charging even while plugged in and run the battery down to extend the lifespan automagically / all the time without user interaction. I don't disagree with your advice on minimizing FCC - just that leaving it plugged in no longer means you don't exercise and maintain iPhone / iPad batteries on iOS 11.3 and new hardware.